# Issue is Java Main class..its not running properly

Tags: java, junit, netbeans, tdd

I have 7 classes(shown in pick below) with main method class for testing is Animalstuff class. When I'm running the code its getting hung and not moving any where. Need your help to solve this.At the end I want to run using Junit.

[classes all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SZOL.png)

running Animalstuff class, see below it hang and not moving forward.

[hung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlfYn.png)

here is the code for complete Animalstuff class.

```
/**
 *
*/
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnimalStuff {
  //  main function
        public static void main(String[] args) {
//              for taking inputs
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                
//              arrayList to store all the animals
                ArrayList<Animal> myList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
                
                int ch;
                
//              Loop until user chooses to quit
                do {
//                      print menu
                        System.out.println("Menu");
                        System.out.println("1. Add animal");
                        System.out.println("2. Print");
                        System.out.println("3. Exit");
                        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
                        ch = in.nextInt();
                        
//                      if user chooses to add animal to list
                        if(ch==1) {
//                              input the kind/name of animal
                                in.nextLine();
                                String word;
                                System.out.print("Enter name of animal: ");
                                word = in.nextLine();
                                
//                              create object of that kind
                                Animal obj = Animal.newInstance(word);
                                
//                              if user entered invalid animal, print message
                                if(obj==null) {
                                        System.out.println("Animal doesn't exist.");
                                }
                                
//                              else add to the list
                                else {
                                        myList.add(obj);
                                }
                        }
                        
//                      if user chooses to see information of all the 
//                      animals in the list
                        else if(ch == 2) {
                                for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
                                        myList.get(i).print(true);
                                }
                        }
                        
//                      if user chooses to quit
                        else {
                                System.out.println("See you soon!");
                        }
                        
                }while(ch != 3);
        }
}
```

Below  is the code for Animal class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Animal {
    //      variables
        public String kind;
        public String integument;
        public boolean fast;
        
//      private constructor to avoid plain animals
        private Animal() {
                
        }
        
//      public argument constructor for Mammal and Bird class to
//      call
        public Animal(String kind, boolean fast) {
                this.kind = kind; 
                this.fast = fast;
        }
        
//      movement method
        public String movement() {
                if(fast) {
                        return "I run on four legs.";
                }
                else {
                        return "I walk on four legs.";
                }
        }
        
//      sound method
        public String sound() {
                return "";
        }
        
//      method to print all the information about the animal
        public void print(boolean fast) {
                String move = "";
                if(fast)
                        move = "fast";
                else
                        move = "slowly";
                System.out.println("I am a "+kind);
                System.out.println("  I have "+integument);
                System.out.println("  When I go "+move+", "+movement());
                System.out.println("  The sound I make is "+sound());
        }
        
//      method to return the animal object of type kind
        public static Animal newInstance(String kind) {
                Animal obj;
                boolean correct = false;
                if(kind.toLowerCase().equals("cow")) {
                        obj = new Cow();
                        Cow cow = new Cow();
                        if(obj.equals(cow)) {
                                correct = true;
                        }
                }
                else if(kind.toLowerCase().equals("duck")) {
                        obj = new Duck();
                        Duck duck = new Duck();
                        if(obj.equals(duck)) {
                                correct = true;
                        }
                }
                else if(kind.toLowerCase().equals("parrot")) {
                        obj = new Parrot();
                        Parrot parrot = new Parrot();
                        if(obj.equals(parrot)) {
                                correct = true;
                        }
                }
                else if(kind.toLowerCase().equals("whale")) {
                        obj = new Whale();
                        Whale whale = new Whale();
                        if(obj.equals(whale)) {
                                correct = true;
                        }
                }
                else {
                        return null;
                }
                
                if(correct) {
                        System.out.println("Correct object is formed.");
                }
                else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong object is formed.");
                }
                
                return obj;
        }
        
//      Function to check if two methods are same, i.e., this function
//      checks whether the object formed is correct or not
        public boolean equals(Animal obj) {
                if(this.kind.equals(obj.kind)) {
                        if(this.integument.equals(obj.integument)) {
                                if(this.movement().equals(obj.movement())) {
                                        if(this.sound().equals(obj.sound())) {
                                                return true;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

Please let me know whats worng in this and how I can fix. The other classes are very small if need I can give code for those as well.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of converting the string to lower case, you can use String#equalsIgnoreCase().

Comment: Change all your `print()` calls to `println()` so that the console output is written immediately instead of being buffered. Then you should see _"Enter your choice"_ in the console, at which point you can submit a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

> Enter your choice:

If you are getting this line in the console then it's asking for the input ch. Enter your input and you'll proceed further.